# May I ask if there is a jQuery plugin to do X?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, scope

If I'm looking for a jQuery plugin to do something, and I find nothing after doing a search on Google, is Stack Overflow an acceptable place to ask for the plugin?

Would it perhaps be better to ask how to do this thing in jQuery (with my code sample), and at the end ask if there is a jQuery plugin for it? Is that necessary if I seek only a plugin?

Comment: Of coures there's a jQuery plugin to do that, don't you know, jQuery is the answer *for everything*.

Comment: @casperOne My lawn needs mowed...

Comment: There you go: `$('#mylawn').mow()`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Definitely don't ask "is there a plugin that does this?"

If you need help, ask instead *how* to do it, as you have suggested. Be detailed about what you tried, including that you searched for plugins, and specifically why what you found is not acceptable. Don't ask for or seek a plugin recommendation - but instead just ask for help for how to do it. But do be sure you can demonstrate what you have tried, already.

If you pose the question as a 'shopping' question, it's almost guaranteed to get closed.

Comment: Thank you for the recommendation.

Comment: This is FAQ material if you ask me. Or even better: `Sorry, your question couldn't be submitted because: Definitely don't ask "is there a plugin that does this?"` ;)

Answer (score 2):

> Perhaps it is better to ask how to do this thing in jQuery (with my code sample) and finally ask if there is not a jQuery plugin to do this?

Yes, it is better to ask this. Otherwise it will end up being closed as a shopping question.

Comment: Still, be careful, because there are those that will see the code as pretense.  It's helpful that it's narrowing down which plugin (out of the bajillion), but asking "is there a plugin to to this" is still a shopping question.  Ideally, the question will be posted as the actual problem in jQuery that needs to be solved, and if there's a plugin that does that, then so be it (and with an answer that shows how it addresses the problem).